# Why the message can't be pushed in the array?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS v1.6.0-rc.2. I am making a modal-like chat box and I've found a major problem. I wonder why the message can't be pushed into an array when I clicked on a button 'Send' like this. I assume that the message is sent as "sender".

**View**

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- I've included the script, CSS file, and fonts -->
</head>
<body ng-app='ModalDemo'>    
<div ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
<b ng-click='toggleModal()'><label>username</label></b>
<modal-dialog show='modalShown' width='250px' height='370px'>
  <name>
    <span>username</span>
  </name><hr>

 <content>
    <div width=100% ng-repeat='message in messages'>
      <div ng-if='message.u==1'><span class='sender'>{{message.m}}</span></div>
      <div ng-if='message.u==0'><span class='receiver'>{{message.m}}</span></div>
    </div><span class='sender'>{{textmsg}}</span>
 </content>
</modal-dialog>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Model & Controller**

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('ModalDemo',[]);
app.directive('modalDialog', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      show: true;
    },
    replace: true,
    transclude: {
        'name': '?name',
        'content': '?content'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.dialogStyle = {};
      if (attrs.width)
        scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
      if (attrs.height)
        scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
      scope.hideModal = function() {
        scope.show = false;
      };
    },
    template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'>\n\
               <div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div>\n\
               <div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'>\n\
               <div class='ng-modal-name' ng-transclude='name'></div>\n\
               <div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'>_</div>\n\
               <div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude='content'></div>\n\
               <div class='ng-modal-textbox'>\n\
               <input class='textinput' ng-model='textmsg'>
               <button ng-click='send()' class='send'>Send</button>\n\
               </div></div></div>"
  };
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.modalShown = false;
  $scope.toggleModal = function() {
    $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
  };

  $scope.messages=[
      {'m':'hi','u':1},
      {'m':'hello', 'u':1},
      {'m':'is it username?', 'u':1},
      {'m':'yeah!','u':0}];

  $scope.send = function(){
      $scope.messages.push(
              {'m':$scope.textmsg, 'u':1 }
      );
      $scope.textmsg="";
  };
}]);
</script>
```

Here is my CSS file if needed.
**CSS**

```
.ng-modal-overlay {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:9999;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#000000;
  opacity: 0.0;
}
.ng-modal-dialog {
  z-index:10000;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 75%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000000;
  background-color: #fff;

}
.ng-modal-dialog-content {
  text-align: left;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 300px;
  width:100%;
}
.ng-modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 5px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 120%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'arial', 'sans-serif';
  color: white;
}
.ng-modal-name{
    background:#4A86E8;
    padding:10px;
    color: white;
}
.ng-modal-textbox{
    width:100%;
    height: 25px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    bottom:0px;
    position:absolute;
}
.send{
    background: #4a86e8;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    height:inherit;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
}
.textinput{
    width: 185px;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 0;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
.sender{
    float: right;
    margin:8px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-family: arial;
    background: #8eb5f2;
    box-shadow: 1px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px #000;
    max-width: 60%;
}
.receiver{
    float:left;
    margin:8px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-family: arial;
    box-shadow: 1px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background: #eaebed;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 6px #000;
    max-width: 60%;
}
```

Comment: create plunker http://plnkr.co/ , then it will be easy for us to debug your code.

Comment: getting any errors??

Comment: I guess you have messed the code missing brackets some where. Fix it first

Comment: @Aravind could you tell me where?

Comment: @SaEChowdary yeah. the data inside the textbox ng-model="textmsg" can't be pushed.

Comment: as @zan asked can u provide a plunker for us

Comment: @JoshuaAtmadja I guess it is because of isolated scope. It might not able to find send function. Try adding debugger in send function check if it is getting hit.

Comment: @nikhilmehta  its a possible one.....@Joshua Atmadja try to alerting the function call and $scope value and at least provide the   error in console

Comment: @all it is working fine. But I wonder where is he toggling using the function check out my ans and the corresponding plunker guys

Answer (score 0):

Here is his working [**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZNwOUC?p=preview) for his problem
I have fixed all the errors but ever thing is working fine. 
Every thing goes fine, 
You missed a lot of brackets here that messed your code.

```
return {
    scope: {
      show: true,
      replace: true,
      transclude: {
        'name': '?name',
        'content': '?content'
      },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.dialogStyle = {};
      if (attrs.width)
        scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
      if (attrs.height)
        scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
      scope.hideModal = function() {
        scope.show = false;
      };
    },
```

Also your **push**

```
var obj= {
      'm':$scope.textmsg,
      'u':1
      }

      $scope.messages.push(obj);
```

Please tell me one thing which the place your clicking to toggle in this HTML, Also do you think it is clickable?

```
<b ng-click="toggleModal()">
        <label>username</label>
</b>
```

Comment: yeah i too tried with fixing those ....i got some more doubts like you....first off all why am getting error "angular.js:12798 TypeError: definition.match is not a function at angular.js:7268" and

Comment: Same here. Some thing is going wrong in his directive .

Comment: thanks for helping. yeah, actually it's clickable. when you click it, it supposes to show the popup chat box. and still, there is a major problem here. no textbox and button "Send" in that plunker.